# Visual Studio trying to test a simple form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just started .NET C# visual studio combo. And trying to figure out how one tests a form.

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form1 Form = new Form1();
            Form.setText("Hello World!");  
        }
```

and in my Form1 class:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            label1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

When I click start, nothing opens, which was what I were hoping for. Am I missing something before I can see the result of the form in pratical use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ShowDialog()` to see the Form:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form1 Form = new Form1();
            Form.setText("Hello World!");
            Form.ShowDialog();  
        }
```

Comment: `Form` is usually a bad variable name since it matches the Class name.  Right answer though, +1.